# According to premillennialism, are the nations in the New Earth still procreating?

Tags: exegesis, eschatology, revelation, premillennialism, new-earth

This question mainly deals with Revelation 21:24–27, but it is probably helpful to read from Rev 20 to the end also.

Revelation 21 (KJV)

> 24 And the nations of them which are saved shall walk in the light of
>   it: and the kings of the earth do bring their glory and honour into
>   it.  25 And the gates of it shall not be shut at all by day: for there
>   shall be no night there.  26 And they shall bring the glory and honour
>   of the nations into it.  27 And there shall in no wise enter into it
>   any thing that defileth, neither whatsoever worketh abomination, or
>   maketh a lie: but they which are written in the Lamb's book of life.

I understand that these nations of the new earth are not procreating, however, there are supposedly people who are evil that are being kept out of the holy city at this time.  Where are they coming from if no one is having babies?

You would think, that at this time all the people that are found in the Lamb's book of Life have eternal bodies, and the others are in the lake of fire.  Somehow these evil people in question should be in the lake of fire instead of being kept out of the gates of the holy city of the new earth, one would think.  The mere problem that sin is still with us in the new earth seems, well, weird.

A good answer will be from the premillennial perspective, pre- or post-tribulation shouldn't matter.

Comment: The question was edited for format and to include the relevant scriptural passage.  Please edit again in case your meaning was inadvertently changed (and apologies if that error was made).

Answer (score 1):

In the historicist framework of Ellis Skolfield, Christ returns at the last trumpet (the seventh trumpet) and the time of the new Earth is immediately ushered in. The righteous receive their new bodies, while the damned are immediately dispatched to Hell. No one from this time forward has any children. In Matthew 22:29-30 it says:

> Jesus replied, “You are in error because you do not know the
>   Scriptures or the power of God. At the resurrection people will
>   neither marry nor be given in marriage; they will be like the angels
>   in heaven.

According to Skolfield, the tribulation and the millennial reign of Christ coexist simultaneously. Thus we are currently in the midst of the tribulation, and we are also in the Kingdom of God, because Christ ascended to the throne about 2,000 years ago.

As for the length of the time periods, he argues that the word for millennium used in the Greek, chillioi, is an indefinite plural, hence can refer to multiple thousands of years.

As for the time when the nations will once again be deceived, he argues that over the course of the last century, especially since the founding of Israel, many nations (faithful or not) that once gave lip service to Christ being their ultimate sovereign have since abandoned even the pretense of following him.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a premillennial viewpoint. Am I missing something?

Comment: My mistake. I saw the reference to post-trib (which this view is) but it is definitely not pre-mil. However, the quote from Matthew 22:29-30 is still relevant to the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer as it is substantially different from my first answer.

There is a viewpoint irrespective of millennial position, that the city in this passage is a symbolic representation of the church, and not a literal city. Taking this symbolic viewpoint, verse 27 would simply be saying that no one unclean enters the church, which in turn simply implies that people must be cleansed first, which implies a connection between "having been cleansed" and "written in the Lamb's book of life".

Answer (score 0):

Robertson's Word Pictures addresses your question:

> "Maketh an abomination and a lie (poiōn bdelugma kai pseudos). Like
>   Babylon (Rev_17:4 which see for bdelugma) and Rev_21:8 for those in
>   the lake of fire and brimstone, and Rev_22:15 for “every one loving
>   and doing a lie.” These recurrent glimpses of pagan life on earth and
>   of hell in contrast to heaven in this picture raise the question
>   already mentioned whether John is just running parallel pictures of
>   heaven and hell after the judgment or whether, as Charles says: “The
>   unclean and the abominable and the liars are still on earth, but,
>   though the gates are open day and night, they cannot enter.” In
>   apocalyptic writing literalism and chronology cannot be insisted on as
>   in ordinary books. The series of panoramas continue to the end."

I would add the caution not to be sidetracked by seeing one's name in the Book of Life as irrevocable: Revelation 3:5 and Exodus 32:33 indicate it is not.

I often ponder how Satan could fall.

Apparently children will still be born there: Isa 65:17

> For, behold, I create new heavens and a new earth: and the former
>   shall not be remembered, nor come into mind. 18  But be ye glad and
>   rejoice for ever in that which I create: for, behold, I create
>   Jerusalem a rejoicing, and her people a joy. 19  And I will rejoice in
>   Jerusalem, and joy in my people: and the voice of weeping shall be no
>   more heard in her, nor the voice of crying. 20  There shall be no more
>   thence an infant of days, nor an old man that hath not filled his
>   days: for the child shall die an hundred years old; but the sinner
>   being an hundred years old shall be accursed. 21  And they shall build
>   houses, and inhabit them; and they shall plant vineyards, and eat the
>   fruit of them.

I wonder if the whole purpose of human finite lives on Earth since Adam's Fall, during which our knowledge is limited and God's presence is, in the words of Matthew 25, as it were "in a far country", has been to give us a chance to make our choice between God and Darkness a habit able to endure throughout eternity, so that never again after Satan's fall would any soul enter Heaven and later decide to leave. In any case while on this Earth Hebrews 6 assures us of the possibility of falling for even the most spiritual of humans who do not "watch", as Jesus warned; and Isaiah certifies that there will still be "sinners", even in the New Earth, in which people do not yet live forever.

Could it be the New Earth is a chance for fence walkers in earlier ages, whose goal was the minimum requirements for their ticket to Heaven, to get one more chance to finally make up their minds?

Comment: Edited for format.  Please re edit if the format doesn't properly break up the first citation into the quote of an author's work.  Robertson: who is that? Please add detail.  Second half: a meditation or musing is not a good answer in the SE format.  The objective is to answer the question asked rather than embark  on a forum type discussion.